# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: There are undefined steps

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

Getting error as "There are undefined steps" while running the cucumber test with testNG in intelliJ editor, please guide with the steps that are missing

the error output as

```
 Feature: New Tour Login Testing

  Scenario: Valid data testing           # src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature:2
    Given user is already on Login Page
    When title of login page is new tour
    Then user enters "mercury"

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: There are undefined steps

    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:69)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: There are undefined steps
    at cucumber.api.testng.FeatureResultListener.collectError(FeatureResultListener.java:60)
    at cucumber.api.testng.FeatureResultListener.result(FeatureResultListener.java:45)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:282)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    ... 24 more


Undefined scenarios:
src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature:2 # Scenario: Valid data testing

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
3 Steps (3 undefined)
0m0.000s
```

Below are the files that I am using under

src/main/java/
  features
     loginnewtour.feature
  myRunner
     TestRunner.java
  stepDef
     loginstepdefnewtour.java

I have a feature file  as "loginnewtour.feature"

```
Feature: New Tour Login Testing
  Scenario: Valid data testing
    Given user is already on Login Page
    When title of login page is new tour
    Then user enters "mercury"
```

implemented all steps mentioned in the feature file as "loginstepdefnewtour.java"

```
package stepDef;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class loginstepdefnewtour {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^user is already on Login Page$")
    public void user_is_already_on_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","c:\\Grid\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    }

    @When("^title of login page is new tour$")
    public void title_of_login_page_is_new_tour() throws Throwable {
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
    }

    @Then("^user enters \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_enters_and(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("sunil");
    }
}
```

and "testrunner.java" is as

```
package myRunner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature",
        glue={"src/main/java/stepDef/loginstepdefnewtour.java"}, 
        plugin= {"pretty","html:test-outout", "json:json_output/cucumber.json", "junit:junit_xml/cucumber.xml"}, 
        monochrome = true,
        strict = true, 
        dryRun = false
)

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a wrong value for the glue path. You need to specified the Java packages to search for.

instead of

```
glue={"src/main/java/stepDef/loginstepdefnewtour.java"},
```

it should be

```
glue={"stepDef"},
```

Also a method signature is wrong

```
-- public void user_enters_and(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
public void user_enters_and(String arg1) throws Throwable {
```

**edit** The files in the project with the naming you provided (please consider to follow the Java naming convention for the files)

```
src/main/java/stepDef/loginstepdefnewtour.java
src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature
src/test/java/myRunner/TestRunner.java
```

**loginstepdefnewtour.java**

```
package stepDef;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class loginstepdefnewtour {

    @Given("^user is already on Login Page$")
    public void user_is_already_on_Login_Page() throws Throwable { }

    @When("^title of login page is new tour$")
    public void title_of_login_page_is_new_tour() throws Throwable { }

    @Then("^user enters \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_enters_and(String arg1) throws Throwable { }
}
```

**loginnewtour.feature**

Has the content you provided.

**TestRunner.java**

package myRunner;

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature",
        glue={"stepDef"}, 
        plugin= {
            "pretty","html:test-outout", 
            "json:json_output/cucumber.json", 
            "junit:junit_xml/cucumber.xml"
        }, 
        monochrome = true,
        strict = true, 
        dryRun = false
)

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

Execute the tests

```
mvn compile test
```

output

```
Running myRunner.TestRunner
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@6bf2d08e
Feature: New Tour Login Testing

  Scenario: Valid data testing           # src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature:2
    Given user is already on Login Page  # loginstepdefnewtour.user_is_already_on_Login_Page()
    When title of login page is new tour # loginstepdefnewtour.title_of_login_page_is_new_tour()
    Then user enters "mercury"           # loginstepdefnewtour.user_enters_and(String)

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
```

Comment: glue path is fine as per me, actually i have multiple .java files under stepDef folder, but i want to run only loginstepdefnewtour.java, thats why i given glue={"src/main/java/stepDef/loginstepdefnewtour.java"}, 
regarding argument i have deleted 2nd argument, still getting same error as "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: There are undefined steps"

Comment: Whatever changes I am doing, it's throwing error as "Undefined scenarios:
src/main/java/features/loginnewtour.feature:2 # Scenario: Valid data testing
", is there something we need to implement for the scenario statement in feature file?

Comment: @sunpat I inserted the files in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but in the code, u have used `glue={"stepDef"}`, but if I have more than one stepdef file and i want to specify only one java file to run, like `glue={"src/main/java/stepDef/loginstepdefnewtour.java"}`, it's throwing error as i given in my 1st code block.

Comment: @sunpat `glue` specifies the Java package with the classes which contain the methods for the Cucumber steps. You cannot specify files there. If your classes in different packages you need to separate them by comma `glue={"stepDef", "other.package"}`.